# Change event is not being fired when changing the textField value in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have a created a project(classic) for mobile web using titanium.
I have created a textfield.

`var txtField = Ti.UI.createTextField({ id:"txtId", value:"txtValue"});`

I have added an event "Change".

`txtField.addEventListener('change', function(e){alert("change event fired");});`

after that when I am trying to change that value programmatically like

`txtField.value = "Someothet text"`

The change event is not triggered. Can any one please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance,
Swathi.

Comment: Not sure but I think change event will trigger only when user changes the value in textfield from app; maybe when you assign some value to textfield you can call the same method which you want to trigger on change event.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. But, here I have created a wrapper class  to create a textfield with some other features, It not possible for me to call a method when ever its value changed(will be changed in many more places) Is there any other alternative way like creating custom event or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it will only fire the "change" event when modified in the user interface. And you would also like to have a means of changing a value without firing the "change" event ;-)

You write that you have created a wrapper class. Then you should create a "setter" function (e.g. "set" or "setValue") in that wrapper class to set the value. Within the setter you will set the value AND fire the change event. This way you only have to maintain the change logic in one place.

HTH

/John

Answer (score 0):

If programmatically changing the value does not fire the change event you can try to trigger it manually on the textfield:

```
txtField.value = "Someothet text"
txtField.fireEvent('change');
```

You still have to call it at all the different places but it's the same line of code.